# How to check what has happened between booting Ubuntu and getting to the Desktop

Tags: boot, 13.10

How can I easily check what has happened between booting Ubuntu and getting to the Desktop. For example, how was my hardware detected and configured, any warnings or errors related to hardware / software and any other information I can see to do a proper diagnostic of the boot process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might give `dmesg` a try. I think it is the easiest way to do it. You can also try `cat /var/log/syslog` but that is less user friendly.